# Windows service compartilhando informações com um Rest

Tags: c#, android, rest, asp.net-web-api, windows-service

É possível um Windows Service trocar informações com um Web Service Rest? Se sim, isso é uma boa prática ou não? Por que a pergunta? É que preciso fazer o seguinte. Quando uma flag no banco é alterada de 0 para 1, deve disparar uma notificação para um App Android. A forma discutida aqui anteriormente é fazer um serviço, colocar um timer para que de tempo em tempo o WS escute essa alteração e dispare uma notificação.

Comment: É possível sim, você pode usar o HttpClient, [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) um exemplo. E é uma pratica completamente normal, na minha opinião.

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim.

Primeiramente, instale [esse NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/4.0.20710) no seu projeto Windows Service.

Após isso, basta fazer uso do [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).
Segue abaixo um exemplo de como fazer a chamada de uma maneira bem simples. E também como verificar o status da resposta da sua chamada.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://seu_endpoint_aqui/");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/allItems").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ImportResultDTO>().Result;
}
```